# Alphabetic GroupBy in Linq with a twist

Tags: c#, linq

I have a tricky question. I'm looking for the most concise, hackiest way of achieving the following:

```
query = (from book in library.books.OrderBy(x=>x.title)
         group book by
         new { title = book.title[0].ToString(), yadiyada="" });
```

The result of which is all of the books in the library grouped by the first letter. `Yadiyada` is because my group object is not a simple string but an object.

I'm wondering if there's a **pure** LINQ way of making it so that the grouping is 'A', 'B', 'C', ... 'Z', but all others fall into a single grouping called '123!@#'.

In other words, I want only one grouping for all non alpha characters (A->Z + Rest).

I can do this in many ways if I get verbose (currently I'm simply making a union of two Linq statements), but that's not the purpose of this question. I'm wondering if someone can come up with a really neat way of doing it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what a pure LINQ way means. If you want to group it with a single query, you can try something like this:

```
query = (from book in library.books.OrderBy(x=>x.title)
         let c = book.title[0]
         group book by
         new { title = char.IsLetter(c) ? c.ToString() : "123!@#", yadiyada="" });
```

Comment: Amazing. That's exactly the type of construct I was looking for but couldn't think of. Thanks!

Comment: `char.IsLetter` is not supported by linq to entities.

Comment: Note that `char.IsLetter` returns true for more than 47000 charaters as opposed to my `HashSet` approach below which only accepts a-z/A-Z. This may be desired or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some kind of conditional grouping. You could use the null character as placeholder for all non alpha characters:

```
HashSet<char> alpha = new HashSet<char>("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz");

var query = books
    .OrderBy(b => b.title)
    .Select(b => new{ Book = b, IsAlpha = alpha.Contains(b.title[0]), Char = b.title[0]} )
    .Select(x => new{ x.IsAlpha, x.Book, Char = x.IsAlpha ? x.Char : '\0' } )
    .GroupBy(x => x.Char);
```

Comment: That's closer to what I was doing (using a range instead of explicitly). But Eldar Dordzhiev's answer is much more elegant.

Comment: is'nt this solution expensive from the one accepted?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: why do you think that it's expensive? It needs to instantiate some anonymous objects. But imo it's micro-optinmizing if you try to avoid it without reason.

Comment: **Ordering >> 2 projections >> groupby** while above one just groups and projects

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: the ordering is OP's requirement not mine. If this is a database driven LINQ provider the same sql is generated anyway. But even in Linq-To-Objects i would always prefer two `Select` over a single `Select` like this: `.Select(b => { bool isAlpha=alpha.Contains(b.title[0]); return new{ IsAlpha=isAlpha, Book=b, Char = isAlpha ? x.Char : '\0' };})`. That's mirco-optimizing at it's best. Btw, the same is true for multiple consecutive `Where` as opposed to a single `Where` with `&&` inside.